# onClickListener in a loop not working for 2nd time

Tags: android

Why my `setOnClickListener` only work once, and then for the 2nd time. It won't work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < contentAndHeaderLayout.length; i++){

            String contentLayoutString = "branch"+contentAndHeaderLayout[i];
            String headerLayoutString = "header"+contentAndHeaderLayout[i];
            int branchID = getResources().getIdentifier(contentLayoutString, "id", "com.my.app");
            int headerID = getResources().getIdentifier(headerLayoutString, "id", "com.my.app");

            final LinearLayout contentLayout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(branchID);
            LinearLayout headerLayout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(headerID);

            headerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (contentLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        expand(contentLayout);
                    } else {
                        collapse(contentLayout);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I don't want to create multiple `onClickListener` that is why I'm creating `onClickListener` in a loop. Hoping for alternative if any.

Comment: Have you printed in Log for check that it works or not?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement the `onClickListener` in your class and then set `headerLayout.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating and passing `contentLayout`, use `view` param of that listener

```
        headerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (view.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    expand(view);
                } else {
                    collapse(view);
                }
            }
        });
```